# Simple MouseMove with AHK moving to random coordinates

Tags: autohotkey

Is there something misbehaving with my autohotkey? I need a sanity check. I have a simple script to move the cursor a few pixels but it seems to be moving it to totally random coordinates.

```
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
msgbox % "1st variables " xpos " and " ypos
                
MouseMove, xpos-10, ypos  
MouseGetPos, xpos2, ypos2
msgbox % "2nd variables " xpos2 " and " ypos2
```

starting position is: 1490, 389
But then my ending position is: 774, 578

Shouldn't it be 1480, 389 !? Why is the y coordinates moving too?

I've tried the `Coordmode, Mouse, Screen`  too w/o any different results.

I normally use mousemove all the time in older scripts without any issues. I am so lost at why this is acting crazy on me all of the sudden.

Comment: Works fine here. Test that code in a script with no other code, and no other scripts running.

Comment: @user3419297 thanks for checking, i took your advice by running on my personal computer instead of work computer. This issue is specific to my work computer (even with no other scripts running).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Random, xpos, 774, 1490, 
Random, ypos, 389, 578,
Mousemove, %xpos%, %ypos%
```

Random does min 774 and max 1490 and selects by random.
Mousemove is does moving when random function selected number by random

This is will help.

Comment: Well done on your first answer! You say "this will help" but you don't explain why. Please go back and "Edit" your answer to explain what your advice will do and why it will help. This will give people context, to help them understand your answer.